# Regular expression to display >quotes in style

Tags: php, regex

There's some text in my db with quotes in it. In their raw form they look like this:

```
&gt;Some quote <br />
Some simple text<br />
<br>
&gt; another quote with random <b>tags</b> and <a href=>links</a> in it
```

What I wanted to do is make those quotes look somewhat distinctive from other text - either in php part before they go to the database or when they're displayed on the page (doesn't matter much to me, whichever would work).

Problem is there's little consistency: there might be extra spaces, other closing tags, etc. Might be a few per string, in a row or not. The only thing that's the same is `&gt;` (not `>` - it's how it saved in db) in the beginning and end of line OR end of string at the end of a quote.

Closest thing I could manage myself is below, and it covers for some quotes - but not those that are at the very end, and sometimes it gets interrupted with random tags.

```
preg_replace("/\&gt\;([^*]*)<br/", "<mark class=\'quote\'>$1</mark><br", $string);
```

Any way to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the quantifier not greedy with a `?`, and look for `<br` or the end of the string by using an alteration.

```
&gt;([^*]*?)(<br|$)
```

replacement should be `<mark class=\'quote\'>$1</mark>$2` so you put the `<br` or end line back.

https://regex101.com/r/j8Itii/1/

Comment: Seems to be working pretty much flawlessly as it is! Actually, there is an unclosed <br at the end of the line, but it doesn't really ruin anything in how it looks. Version with $2 fixes the <br, but somehow it merges quotes that go side by side in one line. For now I'm using this php version as it does exactly what's required of it:

`preg_replace("/&gt;([^*]*?)(<br|$)/", '<mark class="quote">$1</mark><br',$summary);`

Comment: Can you post a string with the quote issue?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, seems like I messed up something when I copypasted that second version - it does seem to work now that I tried it again. 
`preg_replace("/&gt;([^*]*?)(<br|$)/", '<mark class="quote">$1</mark>$2',$summary);` - the exact thing that worked without the annoying <br leftover at the end. 
Thanks again!